# div fat content stretch to page with scroll

Tags: html, scroll, width, stretch

I have a structure that goes something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
  </div>
  <div id="div3">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The content of div3 is very wide and will make the browser stretch far to the right horizontally.

How can I make div3 to only stretch as far as its parent yet when it is too wide, enable horizontal scroll?  I do not wish to fix the length and would like it to use all browser's horizontal space.

I did `<div style="width:100%; overflow-x:scroll;">` but still didn't work.  Not sure what could be wrong.  I also made sure every level the div inherits from has width:100%.  Outer most level has also max-width:100%.

Thank you in advance.

here is an illustration of what I am wanting to do but can't get it right:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that this is what you want?  Just a div that will expand and contract with the browser but the content inside is scrollable?  If so .. It's the `width:100%`, and `overflow-x:scroll` that you are looking for.

```
<div id="div1" style="border:1px solid #000; height:500px; width:100%">
  <div id="div2" style="border:1px solid #FF0000; margin-top:200px; width:100%; overflow-x:scroll;">
  this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content 
  </div>

  <div id="div2" style="border:1px solid #FFFF00; margin-top:20px; width:100%; overflow-x:scroll;">
  thisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontentthisiscontent
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/s5b4yL77/1/)

Comment: I currently have <div style="overflow-x: scroll; width: 100%;"> but it is not working for me.

Comment: Did you view the fiddle?  Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are needing.

Comment: your code worked like I wanted.  but I am not sure why it didn't work for me when I put it in my page.  Is there something I should watch for that might mess with my div?

Comment: I copied your style verbatim and it still stretched past the browser to the right.

Comment: Then the containing div needs to also be set to 100% --  You have an issue with a wrapper div I am assuming ..

Comment: Ah cool, I will verify.  thanks for the help.  Will mark it as solution after I verify it.

Comment: There are many levels of div and tr and more divs.  do every level have to have width: 100%?

Comment: Just the outer most div .. You may have to set it to `max-width:100%`

Comment: Hi Zak.  I have made sure entire tree has width:100% either with inline or style sheet.  I checked this with browser debug and made sure every level has it.  on the very top level, I made sure it has max-width:100%.  But it is still not working for me.